# Query builder with Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

I am very new to Laravel and quite confuse with the model and database thing. I understand that a model represent one table. So I created a model using artisan command without migration and it created the code as follow.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegCars extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Since I have a different table name, so I add `protected $table = 'regcars';` and assume that this model can now access the table by running query such as `RegCars::where('user_id', $user_id);` from controller. But I wasn't able to get anything by running it.

So I am wondering, how does this model able to run the query? Is the migration needed in order to do this? Is there still other area I need to set before I can run any query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highly recommend to read docs or at least watch a tutorial.
what you get is a query build not a model or a collection of models. laravel(eloquent) doesnt exactly know what you want so you query database then get the data by methods that laravel gives you if assume you want a RegCars you need a method like first:

```php
RegCars::where('user_id', $user_id)->first(); // now you have model
```

more info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: I know about this `first()` but I want to get all rows with the same user_id. By the way I have figured it out. I have to add `->get()` behind the code in order to retrieve the data.